# Is there any way to cast signs more quickly?

Tags: the-witcher-3

Wen you cast a sign Geralt stops for a tiny time and then he releases the sign.

I wonder if it depends on something like heavy vs light armor or sign intensity, or there is any perk or stat which influences it?

**The point is if it possible to cast signals faster or more dynamically?**

For example:

> Sword hit => Dash => Sword hit => Sign => Dash

It feels like:

> Sword hit => Dash => Sword hit => Tiny stop => Sign => Tiny stop => Dash

What I want is to rid of the "Tiny stops".

To be clear: I'm not referring to the cast of Axii. I'm also not interested in mods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to change the behavior of casting signs without the use of mods.